# CRM- Getting total of field from all related entity from parent entity

Tags: javascript, entity, relationship, crm

Hi I have a parent entity "Entity A" and it has a one to many relationship with "Entity B". I have a specific integer field which exists in all instances of the related Entity B that I would like to total in "Entity A". How would I achieve this through CRM Javascript? I am thinking it needs a loop to grab all instances of Entity B, and then retrieve the value into an array. Any examples?

In short: Entity A needs a field that shows the total of specific value from related entities.

If anyone has an example, I will award bounty.

Comment: already looking at this source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc677074.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I used a retrieveMultiple to do this and pushed the values into the parent entity.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good use of map / reduce.  http://bennolan.com/2011/07/27/map-reduce.html and http://www.dashdashverbose.com/2009/01/mapreduce-with-javascript.html will get you started.

Comment: At the end of the day, JavaScript is JavaScript no matter where it is running.